# VBA how to sort numbers and words from a txt file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a .txt file that contains both numbers and words each in different row, how do I make a VBA sub that will sort all of the numbers in one column in excel and all of the words in an other column?

[The image of the txt file and how the Excel should look in the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQMYU.png)

I cannot figure this out and I can't find this on any forums.

Thank you.

Comment: Approach this problem in stages. Stage 1: look up how to read a text file in VBA line by line. Stage 2: look up how to test each line (as a String) to check if it's a number (`ISNUMERIC`). Stage 3: learn how to sort your lists of numbers and strings. Go step by step like this and you'll get it. You can come back and ask individual questions for each stage if you like.

Comment: ^^ or, to avoid having to sort your data, learn how to use two different variables as row counters and how to increment a variable each time you write something to a column.

Comment: You should increment separate counters, one for the numeric values and one for the strings. It's best if you ask a separate question and post your code with specific problem and you'll get more help.

Comment: @PeterT Thank you so much! Sorted this out :) just by following your steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for you

```
Option Explicit

Private Const msSORT_SHEET As String = "____Sort"

Sub TestReadFile()
    Dim vNumbersArray As Variant, vWordsAtray As Variant

    '* change filename below
    Call ReadFile("n:\Unjumble Words And numbers.txt", vNumbersArray, vWordsAtray)


    Dim vSortedNumberArray As Variant
    vSortedNumberArray = SortVector(vNumbersArray)

    Dim vSortedWordsArray As Variant
    vSortedWordsArray = SortVector(vWordsAtray)



End Sub


Function SortVector(ByVal vVector As Variant) As Variant
    Dim wsSort As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsSort = AddOrFindSortSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lRowCount As Long
    lRowCount = UBound(vVector) - LBound(vVector) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lRowCount > 2 Then

        wsSort.Cells.Clear

        Dim rng1 As Excel.Range
        Set rng1 = wsSort.Range(wsSort.Cells(1, 1), wsSort.Cells(1, lRowCount))
        rng1.Value2 = vVector

        Dim v2d As Variant
        v2d = rng1.Value2

        Dim vTranspose As Variant
        vTranspose = Application.Transpose(v2d)

        wsSort.Cells.Clear

        Dim rngSort As Excel.Range
        Set rngSort = wsSort.Range(wsSort.Cells(1, 1), wsSort.Cells(lRowCount, 1))
        rngSort.Value2 = vTranspose

        wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rngSort _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With wsSort.Sort
            .SetRange rngSort
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        Dim vSorted As Variant
        vSorted = rngSort.Value2

        SortVector = vSorted

    End If

End Function

Function AddOrFindSortSheet() As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim wsSort As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsSort = FindSortSheet

    If wsSort Is Nothing Then
        Set wsSort = AddSortSheet
    End If

    Set AddOrFindSortSheet = wsSort
End Function

Function AddSortSheet() As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsAdded As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsAdded = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wsAdded.Name = msSORT_SHEET
    wsAdded.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Function

Function FindSortSheet() As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsLoop As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each wsLoop In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsLoop.Name = msSORT_SHEET Then
            Set FindSortSheet = wsLoop
        End If
    Next

End Function

Sub ReadFile(ByVal sFilename As String, ByRef pvNumbersArray As Variant, ByRef pvWordsAtray As Variant)

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Debug.Assert fso.FileExists(sFilename)

    Dim txt  As Scripting.TextStream
    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(sFilename)

    Dim sLine As String

    Dim dicNumbers As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dicText As New Scripting.Dictionary

    While Not txt.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = txt.ReadLine
        If Len(sLine) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print sLine
            If IsNumeric(sLine) Then
                dicNumbers.Add dicNumbers.Count, CDbl(sLine)
            Else
                dicText.Add dicText.Count, sLine
            End If

        End If
    Wend

    pvNumbersArray = dicNumbers.Items

    pvWordsAtray = dicText.Items

End Sub
```